# webpack sass archivo generado

Tags: webpack

Estoy compilando mis archivos SASS con webpack, sin embargo el resultado de dicho file es un archivo javascript, es posible que la salida en lugar de ser un javascript sea un archivo css?

Mi webpack.config.js

```
                    {
                            test: /\.scss$/,
                            use: [
                                'style-loader',
                                'css-loader',
                                'postcss-loader',

                                'sass-loader',
                                {
                                    loader: 'sass-resources-loader',
                                    options: {
                                        // Provide path to the file with resources
                                        resources: paths.CSS +'/imports.scss',
                                    },
                                },
                            ],
                        },
```

Answer (score 0):

Intenta remover estas dos lineas:

```
'style-loader',
'css-loader',
```

Comment: no, es lo mismo el output del file sigue siendo un archivo con contenido javascript y no css, voy a usar otro compilador por el momento ya que no se si existe solucion, al parecer siempre la salida de lo que compila el webpack termina siendo un javascript, o por lo menos no encontre ninguna referencia donde se pueda tener de output un file css, con contenido css